# Change SQL to DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

How can I get these 2 clauses to work in Power BI measure?

```
SELECT
ROUND(SUM(ol.quantity * ol.price / (1 + CAST(ol.alv AS DECIMAL(10, 6)) / 100)), 2) Summa


SUM(CASE
    WHEN ol.price > 0
    THEN ol.quantity
    ELSE CASE
    WHEN ol.price < 0
    THEN - ol.quantity
    ELSE 0
    END
    END) Kpl
```

I tried these, first one needs that decimal calc and second I really don't know how to do it. If price is over 0, then sum quantity. If price is under 0, then decrease from quantity.

```
Rivisumma alv 0% = SUMX ( 'ol', [price] * ( [quantity] ) / (1 +  [alv] /100))


Myyntikappaleet = CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'ol'[quantity]),
    ('ol'[price]  <0) -
  ('ol'[price]  >0))
```

Model rows here

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you please post about 3 lines of your data as an example?  Also, have you tried any DAX formulas yet?

Comment: Forget about your SQL code. To make it easy, add some sample data in tabular format and the add your expected output from them.

Answer (score 0):

As you are a starter on PBI, lets do this in steps.

First create a new column quantityRel:

```
quantityRel = if (ol[price] > 0, ol[guantity], if(ol[price] < 0, -ol[guantity, 0))
```

This will set your quantity for each row.

I am assuming that each row might have a different alv so,
Next step is to create a column Summa alv0%:

```
Summa alv 0% = (ol[price] * ol[quantityRel])/(1 + ol[alv]/100)
```

And the measure to sum it all up:
KokonaisSumma = SUMX(ol, ol[Summa alv 0%])

You might need to filter on product on this one, if so you need to give more detail in your question.